# AWS EC2 IPv4 Public Address not reachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, strapi

I have deployed a Strapi.io app on AWS EC2 Following the documentation provided by strapi.io on their site.
Everything went great but when i try to reach the public IP of my EC2 instance, it is unreachable.
I have checked assigned an elastic ip.
[image]
I have also checked the gateway and security group, every thing is good but still my IP is unreachable.

Security Group  Setting
[image: enter Security Group Setting]

[image: inbound rules]

Comment: Can you show us the security group settings, please? Is anything *running* on the server to access? I'm able to (attempt) SSHing to the IP, so there's *something* there that's declining me.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the security group settings in the original post

Comment: What about inbound rules?

Comment: updated inbound rules

Comment: i was able to telnet your ip address for port 22 (ssh). so its reachable. Your web server seems to be not running . please check.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you need a web serever or reverse proxy like nginx, apache to listen on the port 80 and server your application. Currently, you would not have a web server configured for your app so you do not get any response when you hit the IP Address in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

Check your routing table of the subnet. If it routes the cidr 0.0.0.0/0 to the internet gateway, then the subnet is public and can connect by the public ip. If it routes to the NAT gateway, then the subnet is private and you need the load balancer or bastion to connect the ec2 on the private subnet by private ip. On the private subnet, the public ip is useless.

Comment: Thank you. I just wasted an hour trying to troubleshoot this problem... *facepalm*